# Morphisms of locally ringed spaces and functors of points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, functors, zariski-topology

I'm learning algebraic geometry and I'm trying to reconcile the locally ringed space and functor of points perspectives. Often when one defines a morphism $X \to Y$ of schemes thought of as locally ringed spaces they begin by saying where $x \in X$ goes to $y \in Y$, and then show that the resulting map is actually continuous, and then a morphism of locally ringed spaces.

(From now on, let's just suppose that $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ is an affine scheme.)

On the other hand if $X$ and $Y$ are schemes thought of as functors of points, a morphism $X \to Y$ is just a natural transformation of functors from rings to sets. I figure that a recipe to take the point $x$ of a locally ringed space $X$ to a point $y \in Y$ of another translates into the functor of points perspective as a rule which produces from any field point $\operatorname{Spec} K \to X$ a field point $\operatorname{Spec} K \to Y$.

Of course, this is on its face not a rule to perform this translation for an arbitrary $R$-points $\operatorname{Spec} R \to X$. Nonetheless, by the equivalence between the two perspectives we should have:

1. that any natural transformation $X \to Y$ of functors of points is completely determined by what happens to the field points plus some additional gluing data (encoded in the LRS language as a morphism of structure sheaves), and
2. the conditions "is continuous", and "is a morphism of locally ringed spaces", should translate into conditions on the map of field points and additional gluing data required for the rule to assemble into an entire natural transformation $X \to Y$.

Is someone able to explain how this correspondence goes for (1) and (2) (or direct me to a reference)? Is there a convenient way to formulate how the additional gluing data (besides what happens to field points) is expressed?

Comment: Why do you say "homeomorphism" ? Moreover, your 1- is wrong : a morphism of locally ringed spaces (even schemes) is not determined by its underlying morphism of topological spaces: you also need to specify a morphism on the structure sheaves, and this is additional structure ! It is the case that in many cases there is only one reasonable such thing, or even literally just one, but it's not always true. Based on this, your 2- is sort of misguided as well, since it is additional structure we're looking for, and not a property (this extra structure is exactly what it does to other rings !)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Thank you---sorry, it's late and homeomorphism was from a particular situation I had in mind, of course I meant continuous! Hopefully I've also fixed up (1) so it makes more sense as well.

Comment: Your fix of (1) is still not enough : it is not just gluing data: even over a point $x$ of the LRS $X$, fixing its image $y$, there may be various maps of local rings $\mathcal O_{X,x}\to \mathcal O_{Y,y}$ so you really need a lot of additional structure

Comment: Let me give an explicit example : $X= Spec(k[t]/(t^2))$. Then for any $\lambda\in k^\times$ we get a morphism of rings $k[t]/(t^2)\to k[t]/(t^2)$ given by $t\mapsto \lambda t$. This gives a map of schemes $X\to X$; but of course $X$ has a unique point : there is no gluing data (nothing to glue !!) and no choice for where the unique point goes, yet there are several maps of schemes.

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't mean anything precise by "gluing data" besides extra information, so I guess it was a poor choice of words. I just (I suppose tautologically) meant the extra information needed to build arbitrary maps $\operatorname{Spec} R \to Y$ from maps $\operatorname{Spec} R \to X$ compatible with a fixed choice of what happens to all of the field points of $X$. (This of course is the new question after you pointed out in the first comment that everything is definitely not determined by where field points go.) Perhaps you could suggest a better name for this data?

Comment: I suppose another way to say what I wanted to ask was how difficult it is to write the data of a natural transformation $X \to Y$ of functors of points separately as (1) what happens to all of the field points, and (2) a convenient representation of the rest of the needed data which is minimally redundant with (1).

Comment: Ok, your last comment makes it clearer ! :D Unfortunately it is now a question where I'm not sure I know a non tautological answer ("the extra data is what it does to arbitrary maps $Spec(R)\to X$").

Comment: Dear Keeley, would it be helpful to note that for $X$ any 'algebraic space', a generalization of schemes which are sheaves on the big etale site of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, there is a notion of the 'underlying topological space' $|X|$ of $X$. One defines the underlying set $|X|$ as you suggested--take equivalence classes of maps from spectra of field. Moreover, the association $X\to |X|$ is functorial? If so, look here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03BT. If not, then I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Upon rereading, I'm more convinced that what I put above might be of interest to you, but not completely helpful. It sounds more like you want to know how to reconstruct the morphism of locally ringed spaces, and maybe even the locally ringed structure, on $|X|$ (where $X$ is thought of as a sheaf) in terms of $X$ itself. Again, this is doable. But, before I supply a reference maybe you can confirm that this is what you're after.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Dear Alex, thanks, yes definitely I think that might just be the best answer to my question. I suppose was also hoping for a presentation of going the other way (locally ringed spaces to functors of points) which decomposed the resulting natural transformation more than just it's definition ("post-compose with the morphism of locally ringed spaces"), but maybe there's just no good way to do that.

Comment: By that last part I mean, maybe the "best way" to decompose a morphism of functors of points in the way I want is exactly to do what you are saying and pass to a morphism of locally ringed spaces.